# Trigger a DataTemplate from a Button Click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a a Group of Buttons that are dynamically generated from a collection on the ViewModel. And based on what button the user clicks, I should open a different View. What are the different possible approaches I could use. One choice I am thinking is using a DataTemplateSelector. But how can I handle a button click and trigger a Template based on which Button is clicked.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="viewOneTemplate">
        <details:ViewOne x:Name="viewOne"/>
    </DataTemplate>

       <DataTemplate x:Key="viewTwoTemplate">
        <details:ViewTwo x:Name="viewTwo"/>
    </DataTemplate>

           <DataTemplate x:Key="transitionContentTemplate">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TransitionItems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @AbinMathew Can you please eloborate, I am trying to load a View/DataTemplate on a Dynamically generated Button' Click

Answer (score 1):

I Think you have to use `Content Presenter` to change the `DataTemplate` on `Button Command`

```
 <Window>
 <Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
      <!-- View 1 Here -->
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
      <!-- View 2 here -->
   </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"/>
</Window>
```

Now from your `Button Command` change the `CurrentVM` property, Make sure your `CurrentVM` property `type` should be of `object`.

[Referance](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/)

Comment: I am using the same ViewModel for all the Views here, Rather than Binding it as a Command from the viewmodel, is there a way I could do it through DataTemplateSelector

Comment: I believe yes you can [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418250/WPF-Based-Dynamic-DataTemplateSelector) is an example for that. But the easy way is to split your `ViewModels` and go ahead with `ContentPresenter`. `DataTemplateSelector` will be very usefull in the case of `ListBox` or `ListView` or any `ItemsControl` to show different type of `DataTemplate` based on `condition`.